# Unable to convert a string to a NSURL

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsstring, nsurl

I am trying to turn off WAL in CoreData using this code:

```
//  Code to disable journaling mode
NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *urlString = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"saori.sqlite"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] init];
[psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil  URL:url options:options error:nil];
```

This is my NSString that I need to convert to a URL:

```
/Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/7A614C51-AC51-4F5B-9716-6E3D2F160324/Documents/saori.sqlite
```

When I use that string in this statement, it generates *nil*.

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```

I don't see anything wrong with the string.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the docs for `NSURL`. You have a file path and you need to create a file URL from the file path.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
```

Comment: I read the docs, but very fast, and as usual, I missed that one... thanks again Rick... I appreciate your help (as usual)... :D